# How do you find where lines intersect functions?

Tags: calculus

Where does the normal line to the parabola $y = x - x^2$ at the point $(1,0)$ intersect the parabola a second time? Illustrate with a sketch.

How do I solve this problem? Can someone please explain it step by step, and the reasoning behind each step. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the normal line by noting it passes through $(1,0)$ and has slope $\frac{-1}{tangent}$ where $tangent$ is the slope of the tangent line. The slope of the tangent line of $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ is given by $f'(a)$. In this case, $f(x) = x-x^2$ and $a=1$.

So, at this point, by taking the slope of the normal (which you got as $\frac{-1}{tangent}$) and the point it passes through, you have the equation of the normal line. You also have the equation of the curve. So, this is a system of two equations with 2 unknowns. So, solve the normal line equation for one variable, and plug it into the equation for the parabola. Then, solve this for that variable. Substitute this into either equation (normal line is easier) and get the other coordinate.

Comment: So are you saying that the tangent line is just the derivative of the function provided?

Comment: the slope of the tangent line at $x=a$ is $f'(a)$ for the curve $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

First compute the derivative $f'(x) = 1 - 2 x$. So, $f'(1) = -1$. Thus, the slope of the normal line is 1. Now we can find the equation of the normal line:
$n(x ) = x + b$ with $n(1) = 0$. So, $b = -1$.

Now equating
$$n(x) = x -1 \quad f(x) = x - x^2$$
we have $x = \pm 1$. The final answer is just $(-1, -2)$.